# Proof of limit as x tends to 0 of sin x/x =1 using the inequality -|x| <= sin x<= |x|

Tags: limits

I already know the proof using the Unit circle. But I was just wondering if it was possible to prove using the above inequality. I could not do it and my professor said that the inequality was too broad to squeeze. Do ya'll think that it is possible? If so then how to do it?

Comment: Your professor is correct.  The squeeze theorem applies when we have (1) $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$ when $x$ is near $a$, and (2) $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} h(x)$.  You can use your inequalities to show that the limit, if it exists, is finite (i.e. the limit does not diverge to $\pm \infty$).

Comment: @XanderHenderson The problem is that the provided inequality does not give us lower bound and upper bound functions of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, only $\sin x$. The only desired functions you can get directly from the provided inequality are $f(x)=-1$ and $h(x)=1$. But obviously, this doesn't satisfy your second requirement.

Comment: @Riley Sure it gives bounds.  $-|x| \le \sin(x) \le |x|$ implies that $-1 \le \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \le 1$.  It gives bounds, just not very tight bounds.  These bounds are not good enough to apply the squeeze theorem, which is why I stated that the best they can do is prove that the limit, should it exist (as an extended real number) is finite.  That is, the limit cannot be $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sorry, I misunderstood your comment and thought you were implying that the inequality is sufficient to prove the limit.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I understand that I cannot squeeze it because lhs != Rhs but I do not understand why I am not getting lhs = rhs given that the inequality by itself is true and the proof itself.

Answer (score 3):

By only assuming that squeezing inequality, what you are trying to do is prove the following claim:

> **Claim.** If $f$ is a function that satisfies $-|x| \le f(x) \le |x|$ then $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$.

The claim is false, although it is *not quite enough* to just manipulate the expression to $-1 \le \frac{f(x)}{|x|} \le 1$.

To see this is false, consider, e.g. $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$, and $f(0) = 0$. Then not only does $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) / x$ fail to exist, but there are sequences $x_n^{\alpha}$ tending to zero for which $f(x_n) \to \alpha$ for *any* $\alpha \in [-1, 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to find the limit of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ but the inequality you give holds for $\sin x$.

If you tried to transform this inequality in terms of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, the best you can do is divide everything by $x$ to get: $$-\frac{|x|}{x}\le\frac{\sin x}{x}\le \frac{|x|}{x}$$ when $x$ is positive and $$\frac{|x|}{x}\le\frac{\sin x}{x}\le -\frac{|x|}{x}$$ when $x$ is negative.

But unfortunately this all simplifies to $$-1\le \frac{\sin x}{x}\le 1$$

The limits of the LHS and RHS side are not equal, so the squeeze theorem does not apply. That is why arguments like the unit circle argument are used.

Comment: I did the same thing and I understand that you cannot use the squeeze theorem because lhs != Rhs . But what I fail to understand is why it doesn't work. Considering whatever I stated is true by itself,why doesn't it work together?

Comment: @LostRaider1297 what's left to understand? Your inequality just reduces to one that's not very helpful. In fact, the other answer is better because it actually proves that your inequality is insufficient. I just state why the obvious approach isn't valid.